# Animate div from bottom to top instead of top to bottom in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a `div` which animates to its `height` when triggering a click function:

```
$('#menu').click(function() {
  $('#test').animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 290, function() {    
  });
});
```

works good so far. But I want to animate the `div` from bottom to top and unlike seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWnjx/).

Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could put it in a container and position it absolutely?:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="menu">click me for menu</a>
    <div id="cont">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cont{
    height:500px; width:50px; position:relative;
}
#test{
    height: 500px; width: 50px; background-color: #000; display: none; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#menu').click(function() {
    $('#test').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
        }, 290, function() {
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWnjx/5/)

**Edit: Why it works**
I've placed a container around the menu and given it the style `position:relative`. What I assume to be a menu (`#test`) has been given the style `position:absolute` meaning you can position it according to `top`,`right`,`bottom` and `left`, relative to the containing element (Provided it has a `position` other than the default hence we give the container a `relative` position). If we give the element a `top:0;left:0` the top left of the element would stick to the top left of it's parent, similarly, if we did `top:0;bottom:0` the bottom left of this element would stick to the bottom left of it's parent. *Rambling, aren't I?* So, to summarize, `#test` is 'stuck' to the bottom of it's parent, hence it animates from the bottom. Another quick point, the containers height is important! Because we have given `#test` an absolute position, it won't push the container to it's height, so we set the height to ensure `#test` loads 500px from the top of the container.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was trying to figure out how to fix the base case. :( http://jsfiddle.net/uWnjx/7/ I ended up doing a fake click at the end to fix it.

Comment: thank you! exactly what i need, but one question... i dont really get it what exactly is happening there! why is it with that properties working from bottom to top? could you give me a lil explain to make it understand for me!

Comment: Height increases downwards always. We can force it to increase upwards (make it appear that its increasing upwards) if we tell it there's no more 'down' you can go. This is achieved by using css with absolute positioning and telling it `bottom:0;`

Comment: interesting, that means animate automatically takes the other direction if there is no more space to increase the normal way the height attribute uses? not bad jquery not bad!

Comment: Edit made, hope it makes sense. Read about [element positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)